# Is there a way to "click to drag" for scrolling a large AgGrid table?

Tags: ag-grid

I have a large AgGrid table within a fairly small view-port.

I'd like to support the somewhat intuitive "click & drag" with the mouse to scroll across the table.

Conceptually similar to this:

[[image]

I have the horizontal scroll bar, but many users can't/don't want to use it.

I can't fit my columns any further.